# Корректное завершение QThread

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qthread

Разбираюсь как работает QThread.
Есть вот такой метод:

```
void InterfaceController::updateAvailableInterfaces()
{
    QStringList allInterfacesList = getAllAlphaInterfaces();

    for (int i = 0; i < allInterfacesList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!interfaces.contains(allInterfacesList.at(i)))
        {
            addNewInterface(allInterfacesList[i]);
        }
    }

    QMutableMapIterator<QString, InterfaceItem*> it(interfaces);

    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        it.next();
        if (!allInterfacesList.contains(it.key()))
        {
            removeInterface(it.key());
        }
    }
}
```

Создаю и запускаю поток:

```
void InterfaceController::addNewInterface(const QString& nameNewInterface)
{
    Logger::writeLogInfo("{}: Connected interface with name {}", __func__, nameNewInterface.toStdString());

    auto *interfaceItem = new InterfaceItem;
    interfaceItem->name = nameNewInterface;
    interfaceItem->interface = new Interface(nameNewInterface);
    interfaceItem->thread = new QThread;

    QObject::connect(interfaceItem->thread, &QThread::finished, interfaceItem->interface, &Interface::deleteLater);
    QObject::connect(interfaceItem->thread, &QThread::finished, interfaceItem->thread, &QThread::deleteLater);

    interfaceItem->interface->moveToThread(interfaceItem->thread);
    interfaceItem->thread->start();

    interfaces.insert(nameNewInterface, interfaceItem);
}
```

Удаляю поток:

```
void InterfaceController::removeInterface(const QString& nameRemoveInterface)
{
    Logger::writeLogInfo("{}: Disconnected interface with name {}", __func__, nameRemoveInterface.toStdString());

    auto *interfaceItem = interfaces.value(nameRemoveInterface);

    if (interfaceItem->thread->isRunning())
    {
        interfaceItem->thread->exit();
    }

    interfaces.remove(nameRemoveInterface);
}
```

Если с созданием всё вроде гуд, то вот с удалением вопросы, по сути я его просто останавливаю, как корректно остановить и удалить поток вместе с объектом, который в него передавался?

Comment: Поток следует не остановить, а дождаться завершения посредством `QThread::wait`. А уже затем удалить объет.

Answer (score -1):

```
            QThread* thread = new QThread();
            Worker* fdrun = new anMyObject();
            fdrun->moveToThread(thread);
            connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), fdrun, SLOT(Processing()));
            connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), fdrun, SIGNAL(finished()));
            connect(fdrun, SIGNAL(finished()), fdrun, SLOT(deleteLater())); //!!
            connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater())); //!!
            thread->start();
```

и в потоке по завершению

```
emit finished();
```